# Would like to customize how slugs / paths are created for sub-pages in ApostropheCMS

Tags: apostrophe-cms

I am having two issues with the creation of `slugs` / `paths` in Apostrophe.

**Issue #1**

When I create a page, lets say "Top Level Page", and then create a sub page, say, "Sub Page", here are the resulting URLs:

- `/top-level-page`
- `/top-level-page/top-level-page-sub-page`

It seems more natural to me that the resulting sub-page url would be:

- `/top-level-page/sub-page`

How can I change the way `slugs` & `paths` are created in Apostrophe? Also, how is `path` used differently from the `slug` by Apostrophe?

**Issue #2**

`Slug` changes on renames, `path` does not, which affects any sub pages created.

For instance, when creating Top Level Page I initially call the page "Top Level Page Extra Text Here", and then hit save. Then I come back and change the name of the page to "Top Level Page", the `slug` of the top level page does indeed change to /top-level-page, which is the desired result.

However, any sub-pages created under Top Level Page will have the URL:

- `/top-level-page-extra-text-here/top-level-page-extra-text-here-sub-page`

Which is pretty far from the desired result for two reasons:

1. The slug created for the sub page has the base slug of the original name of the top level page (the top level page has `/top-level-page` stored for the `slug`, but still retains /top-level-page-extra-text-here for the `path`)
2. The "sub" url of the sub-page has both the original path of the top level page and the sub-page, which as from above in issue #1, is not desired.

The ideal flow I am looking for here is:

1. I create a page called "Top Level Page Extra Text Here"

   - This page gets the `slug` & `path` `/top-level-page-extra-text-here`
2. I change the `title` and `slug` of this page to "Top Level Page"

   - This changes the `slug` and `path` to `/top-level-page`
3. I create a sub-page called "Sub Page"

   - This creates the `slug` and `path` `/top-level-page/sub-page`

What do I need to do to make this happen?

Comment: Hi Paul, I just tried this - created a parent page, then immediately created a subpage of it. I got /parent/subpage, not /parent/parent-subpage. I wonder if your apostrophe is up to date and if you're doing this in the context of a project that has other things in play I can't see here. Can you reproduce this in a totally "stock" new project? If so let me know the steps. If not this might be more of an enterprise support question.

Comment: As for paths, they are not supposed to ever be visible to the user and indeed in 3.x they will probably just become a delimited sequence of _id's. They are only used as the internal materialized path nested set implementation. They are somewhat user friendly in appearance just because it saves developers a little time. They change only if the path of the parent changes.

Comment: Hi Tom, thanks for taking a look. The case you tried doesn't exactly match what I was doing. Instead of creating a page, the immediately creating a sub-page, I was creating a page, saving it, changing the slug, saving it, then creating a sub-page. That was when the sub-page took the old path.

In any event, sounds like there may be some funniness on my end I need to check out. Will start with a basic test case and see when things break. Will update this thread if the same thing happens for me in a stock project I can reproduce.

Speaking of 3.x, need some beta testers? Would love to dig in

Comment: Cool. 3.0 is pre-alpha right now, but we will definitely be releasing betas in the new year.